# How to Import Models from one app to another App model?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to reference a model People from my users app, in the models-file of botschaft app.
Unfortunately, I get an ModuleNotFoundError while doing make migrations.

here is my botschaft-models.py:

```
from django.db import models 

from loginSite.users.models import People

class Botschaft(models.Model):
      from_person = models.ForeignKey(People, related_name='from_person',on_delete= models.CASCADE)
      to_person = models.ForeignKey(People,related_name='to_person',on_delete= models.CASCADE)
      msg = models.TextField()
```

And directory structure of my project is as:
[**directory structure of my project**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWzv6.png)

While doing migrations , I am getting error as:

```
from loginSite.users.models import People

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loginSite.users'
```

I have tried using -

```
from ..users.models import People
```

but getting error as,

```
from ..users.models import People
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Little help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`users.models` should do it. Just make sure the app is added to the installed apps in your settings.py.

Comment: Thanks it worked, in Pycharm it was showing as inline error, not able to show the tables from users.models.. haven't tried this simple.

Comment: No problem. Haven't worked with Pycharm but you could see if there is a setting to add extrapaths for autocomplete and linting like vs code.